# Access Struct.key using Dynamic variable Creation

Tags: coldfusion

I have a struct called params inside are keys ch_1, ch_2, ch_3, etc

I am inside a loop that loops over query and use the id column to access the ch_(key) value

```
for(ck in checklist)
{
    n_checklist.status = params.ch_(ck.key_value);
}
```

How would I write this?

I was thinking params.ch_#ck.key# would work but it doesn't. I want to create a property name using another variable value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use associative array notation to accomplish this.

```
for (ck in checklist) {
  n_checklist.status = params['ch_' & ck.key_value];
}
```